# ruby Copy files based on date modified

Tags: ruby, file, copy

I have files (with different extensions) that are added every 10 minutes on a windows share (A) and want to copy them to linux server (B) and do some operations on them with a script.
Using **ruby** and **FilesUtils** How can i create a script that will **copy only the last added files** (or have a watcher that will copy the files to folder B whenever they are added to my folder A)

**update** this is what i have so far

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'time'

class Copier
  def initialize(from,to)
    puts  "copying files... puts #{Time.now} \n"

    my_files = Dir["#{from}/*.*"].sort_by { |a| File.stat(a).mtime }
    my_files.each do |filename|
       name = File.basename(filename)
       orig = "#{filename}"
       dest = "#{to}/#{name}"
       FileUtils.cp(orig, dest)
       puts "cp file : from #{orig} => to #{dest}"
    end
  end
end

Copier.new("/mnt/windows_share", "linux_folder")
```

But it copies all the files each time it is called...

Comment: Your question is too broad because there are multiple ways to do this. Instead, why don't you show us what you've tried and we'll help you fix the problems you might encounter. I'd suggest reading through the example for [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) as that's a good starting point. Creating a watcher could be done using the `inotify` mechanism on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to get the files modified in the last 10 minutes and then copy them from the a windows share folder to the linux folder:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'time'

class Copier
def initialize(from,to)  
puts  "copying files... puts #{Time.now} \n"

my_files = Dir["#{from}/*.*"].select { |fname| File.mtime(fname) > (Time.now - (60*10)) })
my_files.each do |filename|
   name = File.basename(filename)
   orig = "#{filename}"
   dest = "#{to}/#{name}"
   FileUtils.cp(orig, dest)
   puts "cp file : from #{orig} => to #{dest}"
  end
 end
end

Copier.new("/mnt/windows_share", "linux_folder")
```